# Creating an on Radio button on click event to change spinner array in java

Tags: java, android

I am a newbie to Android programming.

I want two radio buttons that when clicked it will change the spinner array.

I know it sounds simple. I have it all working but I am not sure how to implement the onclickchange to make this happen. I have attached the code.

I am having an awful time trying to get my head around how to set this listener. Also, I have no errors, and spinner works, just can't get it to change arrays.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.
Cheers,

I attempted to create it with the listener, but it doesnt work, any advice is appreciated.

Xml

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radiobutton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="@string/radio1" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radiobutton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/radio2" />
</RadioGroup>
```

java

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.canprovselect);


    RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroup1);

    int checkedRadioButton = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);     
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = null;

    String radioButtonSelected = "";
    switch (checkedRadioButton) {
    case R.id.radiobutton3 : radioButtonSelected = "radiobutton1";

    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.prov_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);     
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);     
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelected(
            ));

    break;
    case R.id.radiobutton4 : radioButtonSelected = "radiobutton2";
    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(             
            this, R.array.prov1_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);     
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);     
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelected(
            ));

    break;
    }
```

My attempt at a listener

```
public class CanProvselect extends Activity {

RadioButton myOption1, myOption2;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.canprovselect);
    myOption1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio_1); 
    myOption2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio_2); 
    myOption1.setOnClickListener(myOptionOnClickListener); 
    myOption2.setOnClickListener(myOptionOnClickListener); 

    OnClickListener myOptionOnClickListener = null;

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);     
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = null;


}

RadioButton.OnClickListener myOptionOnClickListener = 
        new RadioButton.OnClickListener() 
{

    @Override 
public void onClick(View v) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        //switch (checkedRadioButton) {     
        myOption1 : radioButtonSelected = "radio_1";      
        adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(             
                this, R.array.prov_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);          
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);          
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);     
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelected(             
                ));

        myOption2 : radioButtonSelected = "radio_2";     
        adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(                          
                this, R.array.prov1_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);          
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);          
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);     
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelected(             
        )); 
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set radioGroup.setOnClickListener(yourListenerClass). Here is an example.[Radio button onclick event](http://www.codemobiles.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=1631)

In that there is onClick method with Toast message, replace that with your listview population code.

Comment: Thanks @thinksteep I am having a hard time with this listener. I have tried to code it similar to example you showed me ... It doesnt seem right could someone have a look.. I have added the code in my original question.

Comment: Please provide more details, if possible stack trace.

Comment: I can't get any errors in the show cat, eclipse won't run. it.Description Resource Path Location Type
Syntax error, insert ";" to complete FieldDeclaration CanProvselect.java /Credits/src/Credits line 61 Java Problem
The import android.widget.RadioGroup is never used Credits.java /Credits/src/Credits line 8 Java Problem

Comment: It seems you are missing ; symbol to close the declaration. Dont need to worry about import never used.

Comment: Is the structure of the coding look correct? I added the ; in the required location ( i don't know how to ignore it) now I get a ton of errors... Does anyone know of a example similar to what I need, Radio buttons changing spinner arrays? is that I can see the structure the on click listener constructed this way?.

Comment: Either update your code here are post new question with latest code, that will help us to check what is going on.

Comment: Got it working, I stumbled across this video, They guy explains stuff great, in a way a newbie like me understands. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H1Tpa59THa8&noredirect=1

Answer (score 2):

In the XML file, change the `id` of `radiogroup` to `radiogroup1`.